# Deploy on kubernetes to a specific backend URL

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, ignite

I need specific backend server address on frontend deployment yaml, but I can't find the method in the documentation for that.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: frontend
  namespace: web-console
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 
        name: frontend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      # remove this property if you use a public Docker repository
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrykey      
status: {}
```

Comment: Do you want to access backend path from frontend pod or do you want to access it from external client?

Comment: the former, frontend pod use a default uri to access backed, but i used a specific  namespace. but now i use ignite-web-stdandalone, bypassed this problem

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? Will be more visible and might help others in case they face same issue.